# What is the principle that the npm module drydock can provide data at the port when the local web server is already using that port?

Tags: testing, node.js

When a local web server is already running at port 3000, I wonder why the npm module [drydock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/drydock) is able to provide data also through port 3000?  I thought once a port is used, then other process cannot use this port?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, Drydock can be run as a proxy or as an embedded service to NodeJS.  The mechanisms are a bit different, but the result is the same.  Drydock registers routes (either HTML routes or JSON routes), and processes those requests first.  Anything that doesn't apply to Drydock's integration gets passed on to the main web application hosted by the server.

It is still the NODE server listening on port 3000.  It's just that some requests get routed to Drydock and the rest fall through to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that impression? It is certainly not implied by the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/drydock

When a local web server is listening on port 3000 then other processes will not be able to listen on the same port (if both are using TCP). But the local web server might proxy requests to a service that runs on some other port (or even some other host) making it appear to listen on the same port as well.

Comment: that's because the web server is running at http://dev.my-company.com:3000 where dev.my-company.com is mapped by /etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1 and then the app needs AJAX data, which is provided by drydock, running and also providing the data at  http://dev.my-company.com:3000